# Programmatically added button not Showing touch feel in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have added the UIButton in UIView in an IOS application. Its working fine with the target actions but the when I press on the button its not showing the pressed feel in screen. (Normal button will dim its title when the user touches on it).

I used the following code:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViewLayouts()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViewLayouts()
    }

    func setupViewLayouts() {

        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)

        backgroundColor = .black
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    }
}

var btnLogin: CustomButton = {

        let button = CustomButton()
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnLogin_Tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

addSubview(btnSignIn)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highlight effect is only built-in when the button style is `System`. You should use an other initializer like `CustomButton( style : .system )`

Answer (score 2):

Use following extension:

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {
        let image = UIImage.image(with: color)
        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        let stretchable = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: insets, resizingMode: .tile)
        self.setBackgroundImage(stretchable, for: state)
    }
}
```

And then instead of this:

```
backgroundColor = .black
```

use this:

```
setBackgroundColor(color: .black, for: .normal)
```

Setting background color directly will mess up that highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your solution looks good. But @CZ54 answer is the core one. +1 for you.